# Bases of free module of rank $2$

Tags: ideals, change-of-basis, free-modules

The following problem might be as simple as it looks.

> Let $R$ be an integral domain,
>   $M$ a free $R$-module of rank $2$,
>   and $\{m_{1},m_{2}\}$ a basis for $M$.
>   Suppose that
>   $$
> x = s_{1}m_{1}+s_{2}m_{2}\ \ (s_{1},s_{2} \in R, s_{1} \neq 0)
> $$
>   and $(c)=(s_{1},s_{2})$ as ideals of $R$.
>   Prove that we can choose an $R$-basis $\{ n_{1},n_{2} \}$
>   for $M$ so that $x=cn_{1}$.

Since, $s_i \in (c)$ we can write $s_i=cr_i$ for $i=1,2$ and $r_1 \ne 0$ as $s_1 \ne 0$.
Set $n_1:= r_{1}m_{1}+r_{2}m_{2}$. Then $x=cn_1$.
One sees that, $\{ n_{1},m_{2} \}$ is a linearly independent set because det$(n_1,m_2)=r_1 \ne0$
It follows that, $\{ n_{1},m_{2} \}$ is a basis of $M$ that we wanted to find.

Is proof above correct?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your proof is not correct. Linearly independence is not enough, you need to show that $n_1, m_2$ actually spans $M$. And this may not be the case, if $r_1$ is not a unit of $R$.

Comment: You're right. My proof can work when $R$ is a field. But we need much more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is indeed faulty. However, the hunch that $n_1=r_1m_1+r_2m_2$ is part of a basis $\{n_1,n_2\}$ of $M$ is sound, it is only that the idea that we can take $n_2=m_2$ is too simple-minded.

Since $(s_1,s_2)=(c)$, we have $c = k_1s_1+k_2s_2$ for some $k_1,k_2\in R\,$. Substituting $s_i=c\mspace{1.5mu}r_i$ and canceling the factor $c$ (which we can do because $R$ is an integral domain), we obtain $1=k_1r_1+k_2r_2$. Now we define
\begin{equation*}
n_1 := r_1m_1 + r_2m, \quad n_2 := -k_2m_1+k_1m_2~,
\end{equation*}
which we rewrite as
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
n_1 \\
n_2
\end{pmatrix}
\,=\,
\begin{pmatrix}
r_1 & r_2 \\
-k_2 & k_1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
m_1 \\
m_2
\end{pmatrix}
~,
\end{equation*}
where the determinant of the conversion matrix is $1$: this proves that $\{n_1,n_2\}$ is a basis of $M$.